# How to set a css class to an array of <a> tags on mouse hover in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, dom-events

I've written a little JS code to change the classname on hover.
I know it can be done with CSS, but this is just for my own knowledge.
Plus, I want to add a transition effect.
This is the code I came up with, although it's not working.

```
    window.onload = function() {
        var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); //Getting ALL of the <a> tags
        for(var i = 0; i < links.Length; i++) { // 'looping' through the array 'links'
            links[i].onmouseover = function() { links[i].setAttribute("class,"a_hover"); } // for every var(is this right?) in the array (a.k.a each <a> tag), set class = "a_hover".
        }
    }
```

It might be because I set the  styling this way ; `.parentDIV a` though I'm not sure.

The syntax of the links:
`<a href="#">Home</a>`

Also, as I said, I would like to add a transition animation.
Like a fade-to-class kinda animation.
It'd be really helpful if you could just LIST the steps to achieve it. (The answer itself would be even better, though I won't understand/learn a thing so it doesn't really do the job :P)

P.S; Yea, I'm new to Javascript.

Comment: The answer would be: Don't do it with JS when it's possible with CSS...

Comment: Bergi is right, why do this in JS when you can simply apply a [`:hover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/%3Ahover) pseudo-class in your CSS? With some CSS3, you can even transform the color/effect as you want.

Comment: Lines 2-3. @FabrícioMatté I didn't know it's possible, I will check that option out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. links.Length IMHO should be length (small letter)
2. this.setAttribute("class","a_hover"); (use this, there was a missing '"')

   ```
   window.onload = function() {
   links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); //Getting ALL of the <a> tags
   for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) { // 'looping' through the array 'links'
       links[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() { this.className = "a_hover"; }, false);
   } }​
   ```

css:

```
​.a_hover{color:red}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.className = "a_hover";` inside the event handler.

`this` will refer to the element the handler is bound to. Using `className` is more concise than using `setAttribute`.

You can find a comprehensive description of event handling in JavaScript [on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Three reasons why your code does not work:

- `links.Length` should be `links.length` (typo?)
- You have a syntax error (missing closing `"` after `"class`) (typo?)
- You are creating a [closure (the event handler) in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). At the moment the handler is executed (when the mouse hovers over a link), `link[i]` is resolved. `i` refers to the loop variable and since the loop already finished at this moment, it will not have the value it has at the moment you bound the handler.

---

That said, I agree with Bergi's comment. You can use the CSS selector `:hover` to apply styles to hovered elements. In this case you also would not have to write a handler to remove the class again.

---

Animation can be achieved as well, but can become quite complex if you do it by yourself. There are already libraries which provide [this functionality](http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/).

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the CSS method, although I already mentioned it, this was just a practice... I don't really get the closure part... how come the even handler is excuted **after** the loop is done?
Could you try and explain me the closure part in a more simple way?
I know it has something to do with scope, and I also know it can be solved by writing the function and calling it instead, though what's the difference? Thanks!